# Why does only my ios project in xamarin forms have a tiled background?

Tags: ios, layout, xamarin.forms

I am creating a xamarin forms project and I have a android project and an 
IOS project. In the android, the layout is ok, because I began doing it testing only in android, but now I am testing in the IOS simulator as well and the background, which fill the screen in android devices, is tiled on ios and the list view of it has a white background, which one the android list doesn't have.
What is the problem? how can I change the background of the ios list and fill its screen with a background image?
thank you.

How am I setting the background image:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.MenuView"
         BackgroundImage="menubackground.png"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

[image: the tiled background]

the tiled background

[image]

And these are the pickers, which I want change their template or do they more transparent, I dont know

About the pickers, I want something like this(as the android is):

[image]

I think about to set in the picker background(I don't know if it exists lol) the same color of the image and get it a little better...but maybe it isn't a good idea...

Comment: We will need some pieces of code and screenshots of the problem before we can help you.

Comment: I don't have many things to post about that...But what I have is there now...thank u @StevenThewissen